# OpenGL - getting a weird results working with a fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl

I created a very simple 2D star shape that i want to paint in red.
I created 2 VBOs for it and one VAO.
One VBO is for the star's vertices and one is for the color values i wish to pass to the shader.

Here is how i created the color data: (let's say i'm interested in red)

```
struct CArray {
    static const GLuint numColor = 1;
    glm::vec4 color[numColor];
    CArray() {
        color[0] = glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
};

CArray starColor;
```

This is my buffer binding process:

```
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(12);
  glGenBuffers(1, &g_bufferObject3);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_bufferObject3);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec4), starColor.color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer(12, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
layout (location=0) in vec4 position;
layout(location=12) in vec4 color;

out vec4 colorVertFrag; 

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * position;
  colorVertFrag = color;
}
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
in vec4 colorVertFrag;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
  color = colorVertFrag;
}
```

And here is the result i get: (ignore the dots that form the star's eyes, nose and smile, they're supposed to be black)

[image]

As you can see, instead of getting a solid red color, i'm getting some sort of a weird black-red gradient. 
If i put the following line in my vertex shader:

```
colorVertFrag = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

The star comes out perfectly red.

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: hahaha, that's a smile! :-P

Comment: I'm still fairly new to OpenGL :D

Comment: Shouldn't your color VBO contain a color for each vertex?

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution, thank you!
It seems weird though.. if i have a geometry made up of 30 vertices, i have to create 30 vectors that are the same? (for one color)

Comment: @gambit20088: If a vertex attribute is the same for all vertices, don't make it a vertex attribute but rather a uniform in the fragment shader.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec4), starColor.color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

should be

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numberOfElements * sizeof(glm::vec4), starColor.color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

where `numberOfElements` is supposed to be number of vertices you have. You must send 1 color per vertex.

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Please also see what i commented to Tulon.